# Protractor - Wait for async promise before doing next

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, promise, protractor, angularjs-e2e

First of all, I've already checked various post and blogs concerning that point and I still can't figure out how to make it correctly.

I have tried many different combinaison of :

- browser wait
- protractor.controlFlow().execute
- protractor.controlFlow().await(

...Still no success..

**My problem**

Within my beforeEach function, I'd like to call a protractor promise and wait for it to resolve before performing the rest of my code.

**My Code**

I've prepared this simple test for anyone willing to help me

```
describe('testAsync', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    console.log('beforeEach - step 1 ')

    browser.get("https://angularjs.org/");
    console.log('beforeEach - step 2 ')
    testFunc()
    console.log('beforeEach - after testFunc - step 3')

  });

  var testFunc = function(){

    console.log("testFunc - step 1")

    browser.wait(function() {
      var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
      element(by.id('twitter-widget-1')).isPresent()
        .then(function (isPresent) {
          console.log("testFunc - step 2")
          deferred.fulfill(isPresent);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    });

    console.log("testFunc - step 3")

  }

  it('test after BeforeEach', function() {
    console.log("Last trace")
  });

});
```

**Current Output**

```
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
beforeEach - step 1
beforeEach - step 2
testFunc - step 1
testFunc - step 3
beforeEach - after testFunc - step 3
testFunc - step 2
Last trace
```

**Expected Output**

```
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
beforeEach - step 1
beforeEach - step 2
testFunc - step 1
testFunc - step 2 // <------  This is within the promise resolve
testFunc - step 3
beforeEach - after testFunc - step 3
Last trace
```

Comment: The "test Func - step 2" is happening before "Last trace" in your `it`, which is what your question says you want to happen (the beforeEach happens before the it).  If you want to make steps *within* the beforeEach dependent, you need to express that explicitly (via a `then` or separate control flow registrations), that's just how  JavaScript/WebDriver/Protractor work.

Comment: I tried to define a control flow without success...  Can you show me a solution?

Comment: for anyone coming here, `browser.wait` returns a promise. There is no need to construct a promise within and return it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this will get the output you want:

```
describe('testAsync', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    console.log('beforeEach - step 1 ');

    // `get` implicitly registers a promise with the control flow
    browser.get("https://angularjs.org/");

    console.log('beforeEach - step 2 '); // runs "before" get above returns!

    testFunc().then(function() {
       // use a then to explicitly chain a dependency off a promise
       console.log('beforeEach - after testFunc - step 3');
    })

    protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute(function() {
       console.log('beforeEach - after testFunc, via controlFlow - step 4');
    });

    console.log('beforeEach - end of beforeEach - everything registered, nothing done');
  });

  var testFunc = function(){

    console.log("testFunc - step 1")

    // return browser wait promise to caller
    // `wait` also implicitly registers with the control flow
    return browser.wait(function() {
      return element(by.id('twitter-widget-1')).isPresent()
        .then(function (isPresent) {
          console.log("testFunc - step 2")
          return true; // tell wait its done by resolving then promise->element promise->wait
      });
    });
  }

  it('test after BeforeEach', function() {
    console.log("Last trace")
  });

});
```

Comment: perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thx for explanation concerning browser.wait promise

Comment: Could you show the actual running output you got from this code?

Answer (score 0):

The two `console.log`s (steps 1 & 3)in your `testFunc`, that are not wrapped in the promise, will fire immediately when you call the function. Which is proven by your output. Then your promise (which looks to be working great!), returns the step 2 log when the promise is resolved (but after the logs have already fired).

And thus, it looks like this is doing what you want? I.e. your `beforeEach` does indeed look like it's firing the async function before hitting your first spec.